# I can't let the data to remain in the dictionary, it keeps updating instead

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I got myself a python book. Currently, in the book, I am learning about dictionaries. The book gave me an exercise about dictionaries. This is the question.

"Create a program that pairs student's name to his class grade. The user should be able to enter as many students as needed and then get a printout of all students' names and grades. The output should look like this:

> Please give me the name of the student (q to quit): [input]

> Please give me their grade: [input]

> [And so on...]

> Please give me the name of the student (q to quit): [input]: q

> Okay, printing grades!

> Student     Grade

> Student1      A

> Student2      B

> [And so on...] "

```
def student():
    studentmarks = {}
    while True:
        name = raw_input("Please give me the name of the student ('q' to quit):")
        if name == "q":
            break
        elif name.isalpha() == True:
            grade = raw_input("Please give me their grade ('q' to quit):")
            if grade == "q":
                break
            elif grade.isalpha() == True:
                print "Grade is a number! Please try again"
                continue
            elif grade.isdigit() == True:
                studentmarks = {name: grade}
            else:
                print "Error, please try again"
                continue
        else:
            print "Please try again. {} is not the right input".format(name)
            continue
        print studentmarks
        continue
student()
```

I modified the code a bit to test the dictionary. I also use python 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you made only one mistake witch is when you append the data to dictionary:

```
studentmarks = {name: grade}
```

it should be like this :

```
studentmarks[name] = grade
```

Comment: Yeap it works thanks alot :). I have been staring at the code for like 1 hour xD

Comment: you're welcome : )

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the dictionary every time you get to this line:

```
studentmarks = {name: grade}
```

It should be like this:

```
studentmarks[name] = grade
```

Comment: Yeap it works xD Thanks laot. I have been staring at the code for like 1 hour. My eyes they hurt xD